# Generate JSON output with MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0

I have 2 tables where:

**Table 1: name**

```
| id | first_name | last_name |
|----|------------|-----------|
| 1  | John       | Doe       |
| 2  | Jane       | Doe       |
```

**Table 2: phone**

```
| rec | id |  type  |    number    |
|-----|----|--------|--------------|
| 1   | 1  | Home   | 123-123-1234 |
| 2   | 1  | Work   | 234-234-2345 |
| 3   | 1  | Mobile | 345-345-3456 |
| 4   | 2  | Mobile | 456-456-4567 |
```

If I run the following query:

```
SELECT name.*, phone.type, phone.number
FROM name, phone
WHERE name.id = phone.id
```

It will produce the following result:

```
| id | first_name | last_name |  type  |    number    |
|----|------------|-----------|--------|--------------|
| 1  | John       | Doe       | Home   | 123-123-1234 |
| 1  | John       | Doe       | Work   | 234-234-2345 |
| 1  | John       | Doe       | Mobile | 345-345-3456 |
| 2  | Jane       | Doe       | Mobile | 456-456-4567 |
```

Is there a way to generate the query output into JSON so that it looks something like this:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "phone": [{
                "type": "Home",
                "number": "123-123-1234"
            },
            {
                "type": "Work",
                "number": "234-234-2345"
            },
            {
                "type": "Mobile",
                "number": "345-345-3456"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Jane",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "phone": [{
            "type": "Mobile",
            "number": "456-456-4567"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: please tag your question with the mysql version you have. hint [JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) (for phone numbers) and [JSON_OBJECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following and see the working fiddle below:

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
   "data",JSON_ARRAYAGG(results)
) as final_result
FROM (
    SELECT 
        JSON_OBJECT(
          "id",name.id,
          "first_name",name.first_name,
          "last_name",name.last_name,
          "phone",JSON_ARRAYAGG(
               JSON_OBJECT(
                  "type",phone.type,
                  "number",phone.number
               )
          )
        ) as results
    FROM name
    INNER JOIN phone ON phone.id = name.id
    GROUP BY name.id,first_name,last_name
 ) t
```

| final_result |
| --- |
| {"data": [{"id": 1, "phone": [{"type": "Home", "number": "123-123-1234"}, {"type": "Work", "number": "234-234-2345"}, {"type": "Mobile", "number": "345-345-3456"}], "last_name": "Doe", "first_name": "John"}, {"id": 2, "phone": [{"type": "Mobile", "number": "456-456-4567"}], "last_name": "Doe", "first_name": "Jane"}]} |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bmjzBru3x147aQnEHxPo3R/1)